# Update the value of textbox after render

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

MyPage.aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPageCount" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" ></asp:TextBox>
<rc:ReportControl id="ReportControl1" runat="server" />
```

ReportControl.ascx:

```
<div>
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" CssClass="ReportViewer" AsyncRendering="false"
                OnPreRender="RptViewer_PreRender" EnableViewState="true" Width="100%" PageCountMode="Actual"
                WaitMessageFont-Size="1.2em" ShowToolBar="true" Visible="true"
                InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)">  
                <LocalReport></LocalReport>           
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>

</div>
```

After report processing(`RptViewer_PreRender`), in `Render` event of `MyPage.aspx`, I'm updating value of `txtPageCount`.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    base.Render(writer);
    TextBox pageCount = new TextBox();
    pageCount = (TextBox)RtDialysisSummary.FindControl("txtPageCount");

    pageCount.Text = Convert.ToString(ReportViewer1.TotalPages);
}
```

The value of textbox is not updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating the value before you call `base.Render(writer);` like below

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    TextBox pageCount = new TextBox();
    pageCount = (TextBox)RtDialysisSummary.FindControl("txtPageCount");

    pageCount.Text = Convert.ToString(ReportViewer1.TotalPages);
    base.Render(writer);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

are you sure you are getting the correct pagecount in the render event of mypage.aspx?
Because as i understand, render event of mypage.aspx will occur before render event of your ascx control, so pagecount value will still be older.

Answer (score 0):

could just move the base.Render(writer); to last line.  If its after render only thing you do is drop some javascript to update it.  Also why?  I think problem is page count not right but you have PageCountMode.Actual set.  So you should be good?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer.pagecountmode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx